# Can't connect to more than 6 IP cameras at the same moment

Tags: python, django, opencv

I'm new to Django and now trying to make an app, which will provide access to live video stream from several IP cameras over rtsp at the same time.

First of all, I have tried the following code with 12 IP cameras and everything was working fine.

```
import cv2
import threading


class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, previewName, camID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewName = previewName
        self.camID = camID
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewName)
        camPreview(self.previewName, self.camID)


def camPreview(previewName, camID):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewName)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)
    if cam.isOpened():
        rval, frame = cam.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(previewName, frame)
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)

        if key == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewName)

 thread = camThread('Cam', 'rtsp://admin:pass@1.2.3.4/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=320x240'')
 thread.start()
```

But when I tried to use it in Django like this:

models.py

```
class VideoCamera(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, cam_ip):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.cam_ip_str = str(cam_ip)
    url = 'rtsp://admin:pass@' + self.cam_ip_str + '/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=320x240'
    self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    print("Starting " + self.cam_ip_str)

def __del__(self):
    self.video.release()

def get_frame(self):
    ret, image = self.video.read()
    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    return jpeg.tobytes()
```

views.py

```
def gen(camera):
while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    yield(b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

def cam_index(request, cam_name):
    camera = Cameras.objects.get(camera_name = cam_name)
    video_thread = gen(VideoCamera(cam_ip=camera.IP_adress))
    stream = StreamingHttpResponse(video_thread, content_type="multipart/x- mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    return stream
```

And then I just paste my stream into HTML file with `<img src='...'>` tag. Everything is working but I can see no more than 6 streams at the same time, I need at least 12 of them.

Or maybe this approach is bad and I should use something like ffmpeg or gstreamer for my purposes?

Comment: How are you running your django project?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What command are you invoking to have django up and running?

Comment: python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django runserver spawns a limited amount of workers to handle your requests. Just enough to make your app running for development in most cases.

Unfortunately, as Django handles requests in those workers, spawning new threads for camera feeds just won't work... Worker threads will still wait for those newly spawned threads, so you won't be able to parallelize it that way.

A solution for that is to use Gunicorn or uWSGI to spawn more workers, so all camera feeds can be handled. Another solution is to use something asynchronous or just delegate camera feeds to HTTP server like nginx or apache.